# How can I add data to a list if this list is an attribute of some object

Tags: python, list

I have an object

```
class Lists:
    pass

for item in items_list:
    name = str(item.theme)
    if hasattr(Lists, name):
        setattr(Lists, name, [])
        append(value) to this array

    else:
        setattr(Lists, name, [])
```

If this object has this attribute I only to append the value to this list.
Otherwise I want to add this attribute to the object and then append the value to this list.

Comment: post the `items_list` contents and elaborate the expected contents of `this array`

Comment: `getattr(Lists, name).append(value)`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `setattr` + `getattr`. Here's a small example.

```
class A:
    pass
```

```
attr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'baz']
vals = range(len(attr))

for i, j in zip(attr, vals):
     if not hasattr(A, i):
         setattr(A, i, [])  # the attribute is created if it didn't already exist

     getattr(A, i).append(j)
```

```
vars(A)     
mappingproxy({..., 'bar': [1], 'baz': [2, 5], 'foo': [0, 3, 4]})
```

Comment: How I can print array or object on html page? like console for js

Comment: @Aaron that seems like a completely different and unrelated question. You should check out [ask]

Comment: @Aaron Sorry? Can you explain how that is related to this question? If you have another question, please open another thread.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, and you start push me a minus )

Answer (score 0):

To add an attribute to the object use:

```
Lists.name = lambda: None
```

Your code will now look like :

```
class Lists:
    pass   

for item in items_list:
    name = str(item.theme)
    if hasattr(Lists, name):
        setattr(Lists, name, [])
        append(value) to this array

    else:
        Lists.name = lambda: None
        setattr(Lists, name, [])
```